# Create dataclass instance from union type based on string literal

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing, python-dataclasses

I'm trying to strongly type our code base. A big part of the code is handling events that come from external devices and forwarding them to different handlers. These events all have a value attribute, but this value can have different types. This value type is mapped per event name. So a temperature event always has an int value, an register event always as `RegisterInfo` as its value.

So I would like to map the event name to the value type. But we are struggling with implementation.

This setup comes the closest to what we want:

```py
@dataclass
class EventBase:
    name: str
    value: Any
    value_type: str

@dataclass
class RegisterEvent(EventBase):
    value: RegisterInfo
    name: Literal["register"]
    value_type: Literal["RegisterInfo"] = "RegisterInfo"


@dataclass
class NumberEvent(EventBase):
    value: float | int
    name: Literal["temperature", "line_number"]
    value_type: Literal["number"] = "number"

@dataclass
class StringEvent(EventBase):
    value: str
    name: Literal["warning", "status"]
    value_type: Literal["string"] = "string"


Events: TypeAlias = RegisterEvent | NumberEvent | StringEvent
```

With this setup mypy will flag incorrect code like:

```py
def handle_event(event: Events):
    if event.name == "temperature":
        event.value.upper()
```

(It sees that a temperature event should have value type int, and that doesn't have an `upper()` method)

But creating the events becomes ugly this way. I don't want a big if statement that maps each event name to a specific event class. We have lots of different event types, and this mapping info is already inside these classes.

Ideally I would like it to look like this:

```py
def handle_device_message(message_info):
    event_name = message_info["event_name"]
    event_value = message_info["event_value"]

    event = Events(event_name, event_value)
```

Is a "one-liner" like this possible?

I feel like we are kinda walking against wall here, could it be that the code is architecturally wrong?

Comment: What is `EventsTest`? Please make sure you use consistent names in your examples. Also, if you are seeing some error, please **provide the actual error**. A minimal reproducible example should ideally be one single block of code and one block for the output/error you are getting. To your issue: Are you committed to `dataclasses` or would you be willing to use a third-party package like [Pydantic](https://docs.pydantic.dev)?

Comment: `EventsTest` was indeed a copy mistake, my bad. My question is not about an error. I did my best to make question as small as possible. 

We are not committed to dataclasses. I'm a little bit familiar with pydantic, but could you point me to a feature of pydantic that would help us here?

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the reference to the mypy error as something unexpected. Now I see what your intent was. Yes, I think I can. I'll write answer for you later. (On mobile now.)

Comment: With raw `python` without Pydantic, you can create [`overload`ed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload) definition, that accepts name (`Literal` you use in dataclass) and value (corresponding value), like `@overload def parse(name: Literal['temperature', 'line_number'], value: float`; `@overload def parse(name: Literal['warning', 'status'], value: str)`, etc, and resolve in the actual implementation. The only drawback would be significant duplication, and I don't see any easy way to decouple this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### UPDATE: Using Pydantic `v2`

If you are willing to switch to [Pydantic](https://docs.pydantic.dev) instead of `dataclasses`, you can define a [discriminated union](https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.1/usage/types/unions/#discriminated-unions-aka-tagged-unions) via [`typing.Annotated`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Annotated) and use the [`TypeAdapter`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.1/usage/type_adapter/) as a "universal" constructor that is able to discriminate between distinct `Event` subtypes based on the provided `name` string.

Here is what I would suggest:

```py
from typing import Annotated, Any, Literal

from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, TypeAdapter


class EventBase(BaseModel):
    name: str
    value: Any


class NumberEvent(EventBase):
    name: Literal["temperature", "line_number"]
    value: float


class StringEvent(EventBase):
    name: Literal["warning", "status"]
    value: str


Event = TypeAdapter(Annotated[
    NumberEvent | StringEvent,
    Field(discriminator="name"),
])


event_temp = Event.validate_python({"name": "temperature", "value": 3.14})
event_status = Event.validate_python({"name": "status", "value": "spam"})

print(repr(event_temp))    # NumberEvent(name='temperature', value=3.14)
print(repr(event_status))  # StringEvent(name='status', value='spam')
```

An *invalid* `name` would of course cause a validation error, just like a completely wrong and type for `value` (that cannot be coerced). Example:

```py
from pydantic import ValidationError

try:
    Event.validate_python({"name": "temperature", "value": "foo"})
except ValidationError as err:
    print(err.json(indent=4))

try:
    Event.validate_python({"name": "foo", "value": "bar"})
except ValidationError as err:
    print(err.json(indent=4))
```

Output:

```json
[
    {
        "type": "float_parsing",
        "loc": [
            "temperature",
            "value"
        ],
        "msg": "Input should be a valid number, unable to parse string as a number",
        "input": "foo",
        "url": "https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.1/v/float_parsing"
    }
]
```

```json
[
    {
        "type": "union_tag_invalid",
        "loc": [],
        "msg": "Input tag 'foo' found using 'name' does not match any of the expected tags: 'temperature', 'line_number', 'warning', 'status'",
        "input": {
            "name": "foo",
            "value": "bar"
        },
        "ctx": {
            "discriminator": "'name'",
            "tag": "foo",
            "expected_tags": "'temperature', 'line_number', 'warning', 'status'"
        },
        "url": "https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.1/v/union_tag_invalid"
    }
]
```

---

### Original Answer: Using Pydantic `v1`

If you are willing to switch to [Pydantic](https://docs.pydantic.dev) instead of `dataclasses`, you can define a [discriminated union](https://docs.pydantic.dev/1.10/usage/types/#discriminated-unions-aka-tagged-unions) via [`typing.Annotated`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Annotated) and use the [`parse_obj_as`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/1.10/usage/models/#parsing-data-into-a-specified-type) function as a "universal" constructor that is able to discriminate between distinct `Event` subtypes based on the provided `name` string.

Here is what I would suggest:

```py
from typing import Annotated, Any, Literal

from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, parse_obj_as


class EventBase(BaseModel):
    name: str
    value: Any


class NumberEvent(EventBase):
    name: Literal["temperature", "line_number"]
    value: float


class StringEvent(EventBase):
    name: Literal["warning", "status"]
    value: str


Event = Annotated[
    NumberEvent | StringEvent,
    Field(discriminator="name"),
]


event_temp = parse_obj_as(Event, {"name": "temperature", "value": "3.14"})
event_status = parse_obj_as(Event, {"name": "status", "value": -10})

print(repr(event_temp))    # NumberEvent(name='temperature', value=3.14)
print(repr(event_status))  # StringEvent(name='status', value='-10')
```

In this usage demo I purposefully used the "wrong" types for the respective `value` fields to show that Pydantic will automatically try to coerce them to the *right* types, once it determines the correct model based on the provided `name`.

An *invalid* `name` would of course cause a validation error, just like a completely wrong and type for `value` (that cannot be coerced). Example:

```py
from pydantic import ValidationError

try:
    parse_obj_as(Event, {"name": "temperature", "value": "foo"})
except ValidationError as err:
    print(err.json(indent=4))

try:
    parse_obj_as(Event, {"name": "foo", "value": "bar"})
except ValidationError as err:
    print(err.json(indent=4))
```

Output:

```json
[
    {
        "loc": [
            "__root__",
            "NumberEvent",
            "value"
        ],
        "msg": "value is not a valid float",
        "type": "type_error.float"
    }
]
```

```json
[
    {
        "loc": [
            "__root__"
        ],
        "msg": "No match for discriminator 'name' and value 'foo' (allowed values: 'temperature', 'line_number', 'warning', 'status')",
        "type": "value_error.discriminated_union.invalid_discriminator",
        "ctx": {
            "discriminator_key": "name",
            "discriminator_value": "foo",
            "allowed_values": "'temperature', 'line_number', 'warning', 'status'"
        }
    }
]
```

---

### Side notes

An alias for a union of types like `NumberEvent | StringEvent` should still have a **singular** name, i.e. `Event` rather than `Events` because semantically the annotation `e: Event` indicates `e` should be an instance of *one of those types*, whereas `e: Events` would suggest `e` will be *multiple* instances (a collection) of either of those types.

Also the union `float | int` is almost always equivalent to `float` because `int` is [by convention considered a subtype](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/duck_type_compatibility.html) of `float` by all type checkers.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer! Will try tomorrow, but looks very promising. Also good call on the side notes, was not aware of the float | int thingy

Comment: Unfortunately mypy complains on `parse_obj_as` with the following error: `Argument 1 to "parse_obj_as" has incompatible type "<typing special form>"; expected "Type[<nothing>]"`

Comment: Seems to work fine with `TypeValidator` from pydantic v2.0b1, but since that is still in beta can't use that yet (see: https://docs.pydantic.dev/dev-v2/migration/#typeadapter)

Comment: Then that goes to show that `parse_obj_as` is incorrectly annotated because as you can see it works just fine, if we pass the annotated union to it. I'll check the issue tracker.

Comment: @QuintvanDijk After digging a little bit deeper, this error seems to have nothing to do with the `parse_as_obj` annotation per se, but is instead caused by the fact that Mypy considers passing a type union `U | V` as an argument to a generic function `def f(t: type[T]) -> T: ...` (for [example](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=25f0b5ee11223822764c8c9fd8f59741)) to be an error. This is strange and not universal behavior. Pyright [seems to allow this](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/issues/4298).

Comment: @QuintvanDijk I filed a [bug report](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/15354) with Mypy. If I am correct and this gets fixed, the code above with `parse_obj_as` should work fine.